# React-Native sectionlist placeholder/text placement has gone up

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, user-interface

Recently I did upgraded my react-native app from 0.59 to 0.62 and after the upgrade I found the text in the searchbar of sectionList has gone little bit up and also cutting out in some of the devices.
How could I make it vertically centre aligned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the solution, I was using textinput for the searcbar and it got fixed by changing the lineHeight value